# Sveltekit: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: node.js, npm, sveltekit

I used Sveltekit and PaLM API. I tried to reinstall and update node and node packages and still nothing happened.
Still, TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null appeared on my console in devtools.

```
<script>
    import Header from "../../layout/header.svelte";
    import Footer from "../../layout/footer.svelte";
    import { GoogleAuth } from "google-auth-library";
    //import { TextServiceClient } from "@google-ai/generativelanguage";
    import "../../css/plan.css";
    import "../../css/white-bg.css";

    const MODEL_NAME = "models/text-bison-001";
    const API_KEY = import.meta.env.VITE_GoogleApiKey;

    let TextServiceClient;

    async function importTextServiceClient() {
        const module = await import("@google-ai/generativelanguage");
        TextServiceClient = module.TextServiceClient;
        console.log(TextServiceClient);
    }

    importTextServiceClient();

    let resultText = "";
    let dietType = "";
    let meals = {
        breakfast: false,
        lunch: false,
        snack: false,
        dinner: false,
    };

    const formatMeal = (meal) => {
        const mealsArray = meal.split(", ");
        if (mealsArray.length === 1) {
            return meal;
        } else if (mealsArray.length === 2) {
            return `${mealsArray[0]} and ${mealsArray[1]}`;
        } else {
            return `${mealsArray.slice(0, -1).join(", ")} and ${
                mealsArray[mealsArray.length - 1]
            }`;
        }
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let meal = Object.keys(meals)
            .filter((meal) => meals[meal])
            .join(", ");

        let mealType;
        switch (meal) {
            case "breakfast":
            case "lunch":
            case "snack":
            case "dinner":
                mealType = "a day";
                break;
            default:
                mealType = formatMeal(meal);
        }

        const client = new TextServiceClient({
            authClient: new GoogleAuth().fromAPIKey(API_KEY),
        });

        const promptString = `Make me a ${dietType} diet plan for ${mealType}. And give me the ingredients and procedures`;
        const stopSequences = [];

        const result = await client.generateText({
            model: MODEL_NAME,
            temperature: 0.25,
            candidateCount: 1,
            top_k: 40,
            top_p: 0.95,
            max_output_tokens: 1024,
            stop_sequences: stopSequences,
            safety_settings: [
                { category: "HARM_CATEGORY_DEROGATORY", threshold: 1 },
                { category: "HARM_CATEGORY_TOXICITY", threshold: 1 },
                { category: "HARM_CATEGORY_VIOLENCE", threshold: 2 },
                { category: "HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUAL", threshold: 2 },
                { category: "HARM_CATEGORY_MEDICAL", threshold: 2 },
                { category: "HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS", threshold: 2 },
            ],
            prompt: {
                text: promptString,
            },
        });

        resultText = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
    };

    console.trace();
</script>
```

After I trace, here's what I saw on the terminal

```
Error: Not found: /node_modules/https-proxy-agent/src/index.ts
    at resolve (I:\ulam-app\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:483:13)
    at resolve (I:\ulam-app\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:277:5)
    at Object.handle (I:\ulam-app\src\hooks.server.ts:23:12)
    at Module.respond (I:\ulam-app\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:274:40)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Error: Not found: /node_modules/gaxios/src/gaxios.ts
    at resolve (I:\ulam-app\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:483:13)
    at resolve (I:\ulam-app\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:277:5)
    at Object.handle (I:\ulam-app\src\hooks.server.ts:23:12)
    at Module.respond (I:\ulam-app\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:274:40)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Error: Not found: /node_modules/gaxios/src/index.ts
    at resolve (I:\ulam-app\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:483:13)
    at resolve (I:\ulam-app\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:277:5)
    at Object.handle (I:\ulam-app\src\hooks.server.ts:23:12)
    at Module.respond (I:\ulam-app\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:274:40)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Error: Not found: /node_modules/gcp-metadata/src/index.ts
    at resolve (I:\ulam-app\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:483:13)
    at resolve (I:\ulam-app\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:277:5)
    at Object.handle (I:\ulam-app\src\hooks.server.ts:23:12)
    at Module.respond (I:\ulam-app\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:274:40)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I tried to uninstall, re-install and update the packages, but still don't work. It's been a day I stuck in this problem. Any help will be appreciated.